# Can't npm start while using preloader-render

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm running webpack and I'm using [prerender-loader](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/prerender-loader) to render semantic static HTML instead of a mostly empty HTML page.

I can `npm run build` just fine, and I see the desired HTML in the output.

However, when I try `npm start`, I get this error:

```
    ERROR in ./src/index.html (./node_modules/prerender-loader/dist/prerender-loader.js?string!./src/index.html) 
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/prerender-loader/dist/prerender-loader.js): 
    Error: Error:  Module not found. attempted require("url")
```

I haven't found many resources on this issue. [This link](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/prerender-loader/issues/9) offers suggestions but no definitive answer.

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
    /* eslint-env node */
    const htmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const miniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
    const optimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

    /* eslint-env node */
    const htmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const miniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
    const optimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        entry: './src/main.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: `${__dirname}/build`
        },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                new optimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new htmlPlugin({
                template: '!!prerender-loader?string!./src/index.html', 
            }),
            new miniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'main.css' })
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /.html$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'html-loader'
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use:  [
                        { 
                            loader: 'style-loader' 
                        }, 
                        miniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
                        { 
                            loader: 'css-loader' 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            loader: 'postcss-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 5000
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's still having this issue a quick solution is to exclude `prerender-loader` when not building:

```js
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == "production"

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new htmlPlugin({
            template: isProduction ? 
                '!!prerender-loader?string!./src/index.html' : 
                './src/index.html',
        }),
        new miniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'main.css' })
    ],
}
```

This pattern enables the use of different templates for development and production if needed.